# javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, countdown

I want to create a countdown timer with javascript that will count down every six minutes. When it gets to 00 I will start from 6 minutes. It will continue like this forever. If the browser is refreshed, this countdown will continue. Even if the browser is refreshed, the countdown will not start again from 6 minutes until 00. How can I do this? Someone help with the code.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question is too broad and we're not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Welwome to SO. Please, before asking for help try to provide some code before.

For this time, we will help.

```
let countdown = 6 * 60;

setInterval(function() {
  countdown--;

  if (countdown === 0) {
    countdown = 6 * 60;
  }

  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = countdown;
}, 1000);
```

Note that if the browser is refreshed, everything will reinitialize.
To keep track, you'll need a database or store in client browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make a button with the onclick function starting the timer using the setInterval function that has a callback that decreases a second each second from the 6 minutes.In the callback, store the time into localstorage, and make the startingTime value restore from the localstorage time value if the localstorage time value is not 0.

```js
const start = document.querySelector("#start")
const timeP = document.querySelector("#time")

let interval;

const startingTime = 360

let time = startingTime || window.localStorage['time']

console.log(window.localStorage['time'])

const setLocalStorage = () => {
  console.log(time);
  window.localStorage['time'] = time}


if (time <= 0) {
  time = startingTime
  setLocalStorage()
}

function calc(s) {
minutes = (s - s % 60) / 60;
seconds = s % 60;
  return minutes + ":" + seconds
}

function callback() {
  
  console.log(time);
  time--;
  
  timeP.innerHTML = calc(time);
   
  if (time <= 0) {
  time = startingTime;
  clearInterval(interval);
  start.classList.remove("invis")
  timeP.classList.add("invis")
  }
  
  setLocalStorage();
  
}


function startTimer() {
    interval = setInterval(callback, 1000);
    start.classList.toggle("invis");
    timeP.classList.remove("invis")
}

start.onclick = startTimer
```

```css
.invis {
display: none
}

#start {
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
}

#time {
  color: black;
  
}
```

```html
<button id="start">START</button>
<p1 id="time" class="invis"></p1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the timer "not to pause" to run even after you exit the browser then:

you could store the value of `Date.now()` in localstorage or wherever you want
and get the value on load and subtract that value from the current `Date.now()` and you have the difference between the times now you can use that difference to do what you want.